# How to include php files in the html code

Tags: php, html, xampp

I have a folder "try" under htdocs and i connect a php file to the html but the php file wont be included. is there something wrong with my code?

```
<?php

include 'init.inc.php';

?>
```

the html and php files are inside the "try" folder. forgive me i am just a newbie!

Comment: What's the absolute path of `try` on the server ?

Comment: How do you know it is not being included? Is there an error message?

Comment: c:/xampp/htdocs/try

Comment: Have you turned on the apache? Do you have the correct URL (http://localhost/try)?

Comment: yes i have turned on Apache and im sure i have the correct url because i was able to run the file ita just that the php part did not work

Comment: i tried echoing a word and wont show up in the html file. 
when i went to localhost/try and click the php file, the error said, "Notice: Use of undefined constant _FILE_ - assumed '_FILE_' in C:\xampp\htdocs\try\init.inc.php on line 3
thing"

Comment: @graced what's the absolute path of  php file on your question?

Comment: @graced In that case you have an error in your `init.inc.php` file, show us your code of that file. More specific, the 3rd line

Comment: *"and i connect a php file to the html"* - Can you elaborate on that? I've my own view as to why your code's failing. Seeing your error message; what you posted doesn't support the question.

Comment: @graced can you answer that question to you ^ that was posted 5 mins. prior to this comment/question. There isn't anything that "I" can do here, so see Pedro's answer, since that is more than likely all the answers you're going to get, given the lack of code.

Comment: @PedroLobito I guess we're probably not going to get clarification on this one. Well, they'll either have to wait for someone else, post full code or fix it themselves. Lord as my witness; I tried. Voting to close.

Comment: @Fred-ii- A lot of people just dump it on here, then let it sit here, after a day or so they check back if it's solved. At least, that is what it looks like. I know as a youngster I was guilty of that aswell, *wooopss*

Comment: @Nytrix Well, it's obvious that the OP is/was present and may have just left or waiting on that "magic" answer that will make all the difference in their world. They are required to cooperate and seem to have failed somewhat. We can only try and we have done our part; now the ball is in their court, *as it were*. ;-)

Comment: <?php

$path = dirname(_FILE_);

include("{$path}/try/mail.inc.php");
?>


is the code for init,inc,php

Comment: @graced . What is the file extension of your file? If .html it won't work, you need to used ajax if .php it work definitely. Please try to include some codes to make your question more understandable for us. And someone not wish your question to be close.

Comment: $path = dirname(_FILE_);


is the 3rd line

Answer (score 0):

codes for index.html:

```
<?php

include('init.inc.php');

if(isset($POST['name'], $_FILES['files'])){
    mail_file('grace.cuteens@gmail.com', 'grace.cuteens@gmail.com', 'A File 
Upload', '', $_FILES['file']);
}
?>


<html>
    <head> BACK UP AND SEND 
    <title> BACK UP DATABASE AND SEND TO GMAIL PAGE </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <br>
        <img src="gslc.jpg" alt="GSLC" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
        <div>
            <form action = "" method = "post" enctype = "multupart/form-
data">
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="file">File</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Email File" />
                </p>
            </form>
         </div>     
    </body>
</html>
```

codes for init.inc.php:

```
<?php

$path = dirname(_FILE_);

include("{$path}/mail.inc.php");
?>
```

codes for mail.inc.php:

```
<?php

function mail_file($to, $from, $subject, $body, $file){
    $boundary = md5(rand());

    $headers = array(
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{boundary}\"",
        "From: ($from)"

        );

        $message = array(
            "--{$boundary}",
            "Content-Type: text/plain",
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit"
            '',
            chunk_split($body),
            "--($boundary)"
            "Content-Type: {$file['type']}; name=\'{$file['name']}\"",
            "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\'{$file['name']}\"",
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding-base64",
            '',

chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']))),
            "--($boundary)--"
         );

        mail ($to, $subject, implode("\r\n", $message), implode("\r\n", 
$headers));
}

?>
```

my problem here is the code where including the php files seem to be incorrect. all files are inside the "try" folder that is under htdocs, i already run Apache